# How to connect multiple devices

Tags: ethernet

I have comcast xfinity
cable coming into my house.the cable runs to a comcast supplied router.On the back of the router are 4 ethernet jacks. I am running my 2 computers using wifi. I am using a CAT5 ethernet cable from the back of the router connected to a PS4 game located about 50 feet away from the router. I want to know if I can split this one ethernet cable so that I can then connect the PS4 game with one ethernet cable on one TV and run another ethernet cable to a different TV and plug into a blu-ray player.
Thanks